# {'message': 'child "query" fails because ["query" is required]', 'id': 'a0136095-9fb8-4dda-8066-d16d378c1a5a'}

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make this request but it's saying that 'child "query" fails because ["query" is required]', I don't believe the query is entered wrong, however, something is causing an error.

```
GENDER = "male"
WEIGHT_KG = 58.740212
HEIGHT_CM = 177.8
AGE = 13

APP_ID = "6bb*****"
API_KEY = "a72cd79*************************"
exercise_endpoint = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise'
headers = {
        "x-app-id": APP_ID,
        "x-app-key": API_KEY,
    }

exercise_text = input("Tell me which exercises you did: ")

parameters = {
        "query": exercise_text,
        "gender": GENDER,
        "weight_kg": WEIGHT_KG,
        "height_cm": HEIGHT_CM,
        "age": AGE
    }

response = requests.post(exercise_endpoint, json={"sheet1": parameters}, headers=headers)
result = response.json()
print(result)
```

Comment: I think the json= is looking for a json and not a dictionary. Try json=json.dumps({sheet....})

Comment: @Arson0 Actually `json=` does in fact take a dictionary.

Comment: You'll need to link us to that nutritionix API documentation...

Comment: Nutritionix API documentation: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_q-K-ObMTZvO0qUEAxROrN3bwMujwAN25sLHwJzliK0/edit

Comment: @AlexanderFernandezRagnark Try to remove the `"sheet1":...` just `json=parameters` (source: https://gist.github.com/mattsilv/d99cd145cc2d44d71fa5d15dd4829e03)

Comment: That's how I had it before but it was giving me:                      
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Bad Request. The JSON payload should be inside a root property called 'sheet1'. Check https://sheety.co/docs for more details."
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add

```
Content-Type: "application/json"
```

to headers, which is mentioned in the example requests: https://gist.github.com/mattsilv/9dfb709e7609537ffd3b1b8c097e9bfb

Comment: also, i tried response = requests.post(url=natural_exercise_endpoint, json=parameters, headers=headers) for the request command so not really sure about "sheet1" part

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :

parameters = {
"gender": GENDER,
"weight_kg": WEIGHT,
"height_cm": HEIGHT,
"age": AGE,
}

query = {
"query": text,
}

response = requests.post(exercise_endpoint, params=parameters, data=query ,headers=headers)
result = response.json()

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue recently.
Your header is missing `"Content-Type": "application/json"`. Also for `response = requests.post(exercise_endpoint, json={"sheet1": parameters}, headers=headers)` you could change the section `"json={"sheet1": parameters}"` to `"json=parameters"`. If you are not planning on usinf the `result` as a variable you could just print the `response` by using `print(response.text)`

So your code would look something like this:

```
GENDER = "male"
WEIGHT_KG = 58.740212
HEIGHT_CM = 177.8
AGE = 13

APP_ID = "6bb*****"
API_KEY = "a72cd79*************************"
exercise_endpoint = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise'
headers = {
        "x-app-id": APP_ID,
        "x-app-key": API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

exercise_text = input("Tell me which exercises you did: ")

parameters = {
        "query": exercise_text,
        "gender": GENDER,
        "weight_kg": WEIGHT_KG,
        "height_cm": HEIGHT_CM,
        "age": AGE
    }

response = requests.post(exercise_endpoint, json=parameters, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

If you enter ran 3 miles as the exercise text response, it should return: `{"exercises":[{"tag_id":317,"user_input":"ran","duration_min":30.02,"met":9.8,"nf_calories":288.02,"photo":{"highres":"https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/exercise/317_highres.jpg","thumb":"https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/exercise/317_thumb.jpg","is_user_uploaded":false},"compendium_code":12050,"name":"running","description":null,"benefits":null}]}`

Pop that bad body into a JSON-viewer and see for yourself. Hope this helps anyone in the future!!